# Paypal Embedded Chained Adaptive Payment

Tags: paypal, payment, chained

I implemented the embedded payment flow of paypal. I managed to open the light box iframe after making and receiving a successful "Pay" call with a valid paykey.

However there is a message stating that "This transaction is invalid. Please return to the recipient's website and try again." in the opened light box.

Any idea what causes this message? 
Please help. Any idea would be much appreciated.

Comment: My bad. I have figured out that I used the wrong test url ("https://www.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?paykey="+token) which is supposedly used in production.

While in testing environment, "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?paykey="+token must be used.

I found the answer in here:

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/adaptive-payments-api/embedded-payments-transaction-already-approved-and-sandbox-oh-my#answer-200385